# Problems installing Repast HPC 2.3.1 on MacOS

Tags: repast-hpc

Updated:
I am trying to install repast hpc 2.3.1 on my MacBook Pro with M1 processor, however I run into the following issue. I am following the Install.txt instructions included in the package. The issue now occurs when I try to use `./install rhpc` I get the following errors, which seem to stem from the GridComponents.o file failing to find the DBL_MAX variable and marking it as undeclared:

```
checking for mpicc... mpicc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether mpicc accepts -g... yes
checking for mpicc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether /Users/alxndr/sfw/MPICH/bin//mpicxx accepts -g... yes
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
detected Mac.
checking for cp that supports -u... no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking how to run the C preprocessor... mpicc -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for Boost headers version >= 0... yes
checking for Boost's header version... 1_78
checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin20.6.0
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin20.6.0
checking for the toolset name used by Boost for /Users/alxndr/sfw/MPICH/bin//mpicxx... xgcc42 -xgcc
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /Users/alxndr/sfw/MPICH/bin//mpicxx -E
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp... yes
checking for the Boost serialization library... yes
checking boost/mpi.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/mpi.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/mpi.hpp... yes
checking for the Boost mpi library... yes
checking boost/system/error_code.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/system/error_code.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/system/error_code.hpp... yes
checking for the Boost system library... yes
checking boost/filesystem/path.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/filesystem/path.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/filesystem/path.hpp... yes
checking for the Boost filesystem library... yes
checking for boost/system/error_code.hpp... (cached) yes
checking for the Boost system library... (cached) yes
checking for curl_version in -lcurl... yes
checking for nc_open in -lnetcdf... yes
checking netcdfcpp.h usability... yes
checking netcdfcpp.h presence... yes
checking for netcdfcpp.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
checking for error_at_line... no
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for floor... yes
checking for rint... yes
checking for sqrt... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
  CC        src/repast_hpc/AgentId.o
  CC        src/repast_hpc/AgentImporterExporter.o
  CC        src/repast_hpc/AgentRequest.o
  CC        src/repast_hpc/AgentStatus.o
  CC        src/repast_hpc/CartesianTopology.o
  CC        src/repast_hpc/Graph.o
  CC        src/repast_hpc/GridComponents.o
src/repast_hpc/GridComponents.cpp:165:64: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DBL_MAX'
      if(out[i] >= maxs[i])       out[i] = nextafter(maxs[i], -DBL_MAX);
                                                               ^
src/repast_hpc/GridComponents.cpp:166:64: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DBL_MAX'
      else if(out[i] < mins[i])   out[i] = nextafter(mins[i],  DBL_MAX);
                                                               ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [src/repast_hpc/GridComponents.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you check the bootstrap.log for more details about the error. If you could then edit your question to include that info, that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question and included the bootstrap log.

Comment: Updated the question once more as I discovered a further issue related to the install.sh installation of netcdf, and more specifically to NetCDF-cxx.

Comment: Yeah, I've found that too. I've posted a workaround here: https://github.com/Repast/repast.hpc/issues/7, but I'm still trying to get boost mpi to correctly install.

Comment: Both fixes for netcdf and boost seem to work and I managed to install them. However, the repast-hpc install scrips seems to fail. I updated the question with the new error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've outlined all the required fixes (including the DBL_MAX fix) here: https://github.com/Repast/repast.hpc/issues/7. With those in place, the zombies and rumor demo models work on macOS on an M1 Max laptop.

All that said, and as an aside, we typically do our repast hpc and repast4py development work on a Linux VM running under Parallels or VMWare Fusion on a Mac. This is because that more closely matches the cluster or HPC environments we ultimately run the models on.